# google sheets checkbox increment counter

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, auto-increment

I am making a checkbox inventory counter that auto increments

I have tried many if then statements to increase a cell value when a box or multiple boxes is check. The best I could do was display a number but it disappears once the checkboxes are unchecked. So I would like and cell to auto increase by 1 after the last or all boxes are checked

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Comment: Something like `=COUNTIF(A1:A10,TRUE)` should do that. See more at: [COUNTIF](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093480)

Comment: A script will be required to increment a number and keep it that way even when those checkboxes are unticked. The requirements are too vague to suggest a concrete solution.

Comment: "disappears once the checkboxes are unchecked" - what you need is a script